# How do you run a jar file on boot (Ubuntu 11.10)?

Tags: java, ubuntu, service, jar

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. I've written a simple listener application in Java which runs properly (tested). Basically this java application in a loop that waits for an event every 60 seconds. After successfully jar-ing this file, I'm able to execute the file using

`/usr/bin/java -jar /home/testuser/MyApp.jar`

What I want to do is a create a shell script that starts this application when Ubuntu boots. My autostart.sh script is really simple:

```
#!bin/bash
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/testuser/MyApp.jar
```

Then I use the following commands to put it in the init.d directory:

```
#: sudo cp /home/testuser/autostart.sh /etc/init.d
#: chmod 777 /etc/init.d/autostart.sh
#: sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/autostart.sh defaults
```

Then I restart and use top to see if Java is running, but I dont see this. Does anyone know what the best way to implement this?

Using "ls -l /etc/rc?.d/*autostart" I get:

@hovanessyan: my output for that command is -

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 2012-03-19 14:26 /etc/rc0.d/K20autostart -> ../init.d/autostart

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 2012-03-19 14:26 /etc/rc1.d/K20autostart -> ../init.d/autostart

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 2012-03-19 14:26 /etc/rc2.d/S20autostart -> ../init.d/autostart

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 2012-03-19 14:26 /etc/rc3.d/S20autostart -> ../init.d/autostart

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 2012-03-19 14:26 /etc/rc4.d/S20autostart -> ../init.d/autostart

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 2012-03-19 14:26 /etc/rc5.d/S20autostart -> ../init.d/autostart

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 2012-03-19 14:26 /etc/rc6.d/K20autostart -> ../init.d/autostart
```

Comment: have you tried creating a `@reboot` cronjob?

Comment: will this run at boot regardless if a user logs in?

Comment: i think this only starts the script after a reboot and not after a cold boot. If I'm not mistaken, this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: your approach seems correct. Can you please paste output of the following: ls -l /etc/rc?.d/*autostart

Comment: Keep in mind Ubuntu is moving away from SysV scripts towards upstart jobs. Here's getting started with upstart: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Comment: @hovanessyan: i've edited my question to include the output for that command. I'll take a look at upstart - i thought a script like this would be simple enough but i guess not!

Comment: @codedawg82 I assume you boot to runlevel 3 right?

Comment: No, i'm booting to runlevel 2. Should this make a difference? I'll try bootings to runlevel 3 and get back you...

Comment: I finally figured it out --- I was using #: top to see if the jvm was running but apparently the process was just using so little memory it wasn't showing up! however, it was working in the background. Sorry about that everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Create an upstart job and set the appropriate run level(s). Look at the other jobs in `/etc/init` with the .conf extensions for examples.